# The sum of the product

Tags: summation

I am wondering if the following two assumptions are true:

1. $\sum(a-b)(c-d)$=$\sum(ac-ad-bc+bd)$=$\sum ac-\sum ad-\sum bc+\sum bd$?
2. $\sum(a-b)^2$=$\sum(a^2-2ab+b^2)=\sum a^2-2\sum ab+\sum b^2$?

Edited: typing mistake correction

Comment: yes , by the associativity property of the addition ( commutativity too )

Comment: It's only true for finite sums though.